# Windows undo software uninstall

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, uninstall

Is there any possible way, a solution to undo uninstall of software in Windows 7, 8 or 10?

Maybe some software that allows this functionality?

For instance: I installed OpenOffice and then uninstalled it later, but after some time I decide that I shouldn't have done it, so I wish to recover my installation.

Comment: how about keep the original OpenOffice installer and reinstall again ?

Comment: @Hongkie Yes, but that would mean setting all my preferences again and imaging if it's Rad Studio we are installing

Comment: Do a *System Restore*? Almost all uninstallers leave a system restore point before uninstalling a certain program.

Answer (score 2):

As you are mentioning Rad Studio, it's completely different story altogether.

**Development efforts (e.g Rad Studio, Visual studio .NET) should always be done in virtualized environment**. Virtualized environment (also called VM - virtual machines) offers features called snapshots. Snapshots would be very handy to resolve your issues, i.e. restoring environment to specific point in the past, without reinstalling Rad Studio.

Check if your laptop / desktop support virtualization. Usually newer computers support virtualization.

For virtualization / VM information and snapshot: here is the link
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-snapshots-in-virtualbox/

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Posted before OP further clarified the desired applications. Please refer to Hongkie's answer when considering development environments.**

I am unaware of any software that offers that functionality beyond simply reinstalling from the same executable you used originally. I suppose you could save the installer executable, but you would probably be better off downloading the most up-to-date release.

Some applications leave settings files in place in case of a reinstall. For these situations, installing the application again should retain settings from the previous install. Many applications, however, do not. If there is no persistent settings file, I see little advantage in "undoing an uninstall" rather than just doing a clean install of the most recent version of your software. **You could manually back up your settings for a particular application, and pray that the same file is supported in later versions.**

You mentioned OpenOffice, so I did not consider the possibility of licensing issues caused by failing to release a license prior to uninstalling.

**tl;dr: Just reinstall. Save your settings file if you want, but this is application-specific**